# Globally catch ModelNotFoundException on Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I am trying to catch the **ModelNotFoundException** globally from the app\Exceptions\Handler class, so to not have to check for it on every single controller.

But it does not work, although it works fine from inside a controller:

```
try {

        $asset = Asset::findOrFail($asset_id);

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException)
        {
            $model = explode('\\', $e->getModel());
            return $this->respondWithRecordNotFound(end($model) . ' record not found');
        }

        return $this->respondWithGeneralError($e->getMessage());
    }
```

app\Exceptions\Handler:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{

    if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) 
    {
        $model = explode('\\', $exception->getModel());
        return $this->respondWithRecordNotFound(end($model) . ' record not found');
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: What did you add to Handler?

Comment: @Devon updated with the Handler

Comment: So what does not work mean?  An error or you're getting the standard 404?

Comment: @Devon it means that the code is getting ignored

Comment: It looks fine, although I'm not sure what your respondWithRecordNotFound method is doing.  Hook up a debugger and set a breakpoint in your render function.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your `respondWithRecordNotFound` is doing. I guess the issue might lie there.

In any case, I just tried it out and this works for me. In `App\Exceptions\Handler.php@render`

```
if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException) {
    return response()->view(
        'errors.404', 
        ["message" => $e->getModel() . ' record not found'], 
        404
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have added the use in the Handler.php

```
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
```